# Rotate Sprite on touch swift 3 IOS

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to replicate the flappy bird game as a practise. 
When playing flappy bird when you touched the screen the bird tilted upwards slightly (and went up) then when you released he would kind of rotate downwards and drop.

I have all the physics set up I just need to know how to rotate the bird up (whilst keeping the flappy wing animation) and then rotate him to face down again when you let go.

Easy I'm sure?...

Answer (score 0):

In update frames method put

**-Swift 3-**

```
let value = Bird.physicsBody!.velocity.dy * ( Bird.physicsBody!.velocity.dy < 0 ? 0.005 : 0.001 )
Bird.zRotation = min( max(-0.5 //determines how much rotation when falling down, value), 1 //determines how much when jumping up )
```

bird will rotate whenever impulse is applied

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing `SpriteKit` I would consider rotating your coordinate system as in the second answer to this question. @ToddFincannon proposes to save the graphics state, translate/rotate your coordinate system (most probably to the center of your sprite), draw and restore. Roughly copying his answer that will translate into

```
let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
c.saveGState()
c.translateBy(x: sprite.midX, y: midY)
c.rotate(by: angle * .pi / 180)
// Draw your sprite at 0, 0 (it is already translated)
c.restoreGState()
```

In order to be rotated upwards you will likely need a negative angle.